# Cakephp Auth logs out only remotely

Tags: php, cakephp

On localhost i have no problem at all. i can login access all sites and go through the process of the site without a problem.

Now when i put it remotely i get logged out as soon as i change page (aka i am being redirected to my login view no matter what link i press)

My AppController loos like this:

```
    <?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'Acl',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authorize' => array(
                'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
            )
        ),
        'Session'
    );
    public $uses = array
    (
        'Category'
    );

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
        //Configure AuthComponent
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index');

        $this->set('menu_categories', $this->Category->find('all'));

    }
}
```

Please tell me if you need more information (also if you wish to try this issue go to my page ([my  domain](http://www.udlejnings-priser.dk)
 log in as test password test123

Comment: Are sessions cookies being properly persisted?

Comment: @MikeBrant how can i check this?

Comment: Look at the cookies you have in your favorite web development tool for your browser.

Comment: @Mike it is setting a cookie which persits even when it logs me out. I am starting to think that something is interfering with my session but how do i test that?